# Proving a Sequence Converges Using the Epsilon Definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

So I need to prove $\left(\frac{n}{2n-51}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. I get that $\left|\frac{n}{2n-51} -\frac{1}{2} \right| = \frac{51}{4n-102}$ and I get stuck. From here I know I'm supposed to get $51$ over a constant times $n$ is less than $\epsilon$ but I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I should clarify; I'm searching for N currently- the subtraction occurring in the denominator is throwing me off.

Comment: Then look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did was the right way (but you have to be careful, your equation involving the absolute value is wrong without restrictions on the size of $n$). Now you want for any $\varepsilon > 0$, that $$\frac{51}{4n-102} \overset{!}{<} \varepsilon$$ Hence $$\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{51}{\varepsilon} + 102\right)< n$$ To make the proof formal, let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$ defined by $$N := \max\left\{26,\left\lfloor\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{51}{\varepsilon} + 102\right)\right\rfloor\right\}$$ Then for any $n > N$ we get $$\left|\frac{n}{2n-51} -\frac{1}{2} \right| = \frac{51}{4n-102} < 51\frac{\varepsilon}{51} = \varepsilon$$ by $$4n - 102 \geqslant 4(N+1) - 102 > 4\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{51}{\varepsilon} + 102\right) - 102 =\frac{51}{\varepsilon}$$ and similar for the case where $N = 26$.

Comment: All right, I definitely understand why N is defined as the max of those two numbers, but why is the ceiling function necessary in the definition of N?

Comment: The floor (which yields the sharpest bound) or the ceiling function makes sure that $N$ is a natural number. In general you could define $N$ as any natural number which is larger than $\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{51}{\varepsilon}+102\right)$.